# Request multiple value on firebase during the download [Swift]!

Tags: swift, firebase

I got some user on firebase and for each user I got an index.
I got a totalUser child , too.
I am taking 4 random user and I am saving the 4 index into an array. How can I download the 4 user information by id that I’ve stored into the array with firebase?

Comment: Firebase has no concept of randomization. It will only download ordered by a key or a value. If you want to randomly select a node, craft some code that selects a number from 0 to 496, append it to the string of 'user', so the resultant string is userX, then use that as the key of the node you want to observe.

Comment: user0 etc was an example. My user0 etc are the uid of user.  My idea was: I download all uid and get one random and start the download limited by 4 from this uid random but the problem is if I got 10.000+ users because I can’t download 10k of uid ahaha

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The OP totally changed the original question after it was posted, so this answer doesn't exactly apply. Will leave it for reading as it may provide direction for future readers.

---

There are many ways to approach this issue.

From what I understand, the OP has a /users node with a number of users - could be thousands - and they want to select a random user and perform a task based on that users info. The users are all stored with their uid's as the parent to each user node.

```
users
  uid_x
    some user data
  uid_y
    some user data
```

One way would to be load all of the users within the users node and randomly select one in code. As the OP noted, it's probably not practical if there are thousands of users.

Another option is to store an index within each user node, then a random number generator to select a random number between 0 and the total number of users

```
users
  uid_x
    some user data
    index: 0
  uid_y
    some user data
    index: 1
```

That's a very practical method to select a random user. However, it starts to fall apart if users are deleted as the random number generator could select an index of a user that was deleted.

Another option is to have a node that only stores user id's, load those in and select a random one. This works better than the first solution as only the uids are loaded which would contain a fraction of the amount of data compared to the entire users node

```
users
  uid_x
    some user data
  uid_y
    some user data

all_uids
   uid_x: true
   uid_y: true
```

It still becomes cumbersome for tens-of-thousands of users.

Another option is a re-sequencing approach - similar to the second solution. In this approach, when a user is deleted, the index from that user down to the last user is updated with a new index to reflect it's actual position. That way, the numerical sequence remain intact and the random number generator in code can still select a number from 0 to the total number of users.

There's more options as well but that's a starting point.

Comment: I already got the random index of each user but how can i download only 4 user by this index? I want request directly 4 user to firebase and not call 4 times the download for each user

Comment: @Michele That question doesn't make sense if each user node has the UID as it's key or you have discreet indexes for each user. In other words, if the random number generator selects '9', you would only have one user with index 9, not several users with the same index.. However, if you are stating you generate 4 different indexes and want to load those users, you would simple iterate over each index and load each user using .observeSingleEvent for each one.

Comment: Sorry, you don’t understand. I’ll got 4 different index and I want download one time the 4 users but firebase can’t do it. I’ll do it with MySQL, its better than firebase

Comment: @Michele You cannot 'do it' with SQL either. In databases, data is sequential and you will have to perform a select in SQL to select the 4 items you want. You will essentially do the same thing in Firebase. SQL is not better, it's different. Going forward, please don't post questions that you are not interesting in having answered. We spend a LOT of time trying to help!

Comment: To clarify; suppose you want to download all users with the first_name of "bob'. Performing a query using *usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "first_name").queryEqual(toValue: "bob").observeSingleEvent* will do just that - whether it's 4 nodes or 400. So yes, Firebase can do that.